# Create rake task to compile SASS file that @import's from gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, rake, sprockets

I'd like to create a rake task compiles some SASS files that refer to @import's in gems to speed up my development workflow.

**Some background**

We've recently added a new theme to our rails application, and the sass stylesheets really bog down the assset pipeline in development environment (to the extend of frequently causing timeouts)

The theme relies heavily on imports and mixins which would be very tedious to try and manually convert into files that we could just `*= require` as some guides suggest.

The files are relatively static, so there's very little reason they should be compiled on every request BUT I have other assets that are worked on frequently so I'd prefer not to rely on `rake assets:precompile`)

All of the themes are included by a single file (`theme/base.scss`) that `@import`s all the rest, so I was thinking an easy solution would be to take that file out of `application.css` and create a rake task `theme:precompile` that compiles it to theme.css which is then required by `application.css`

That way if we do need to tweak the theme file, we can update it and run the rake task, and then the asset pipeline just has a simple static css file to work with.

At first, I tried setting up a rake file that simply invokes sass

```
desc 'Precompile the theme SASS to save on development time'
task :precompile do |t, args|
  dir = 'app/assets/stylesheets/'
  source = 'theme/base.scss'
  dest = 'theme.css'

  source_path = dir + src
  dest_path = dir + dst
  puts "Precomipling #{source_path} to #{dest} ..."

  `sass "#{source_path}" "#{dest_path}"`
end
```

but that failed because the theme relies on the bootstrap-sass gem, giving

```
Error: File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap-sprockets.
```

So it seems my rake task needs to load the whole sprockets environment, or otherwise figure out how to tell SASS where the bootstrap-sass gem is.

Is this possible? Or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find an answer to the question I asked.

In the end, my workaround was that I pulled the @imports into a separate file that stayed in the asset pipeline and used the raketask in my question.